# MySQL - Not getting results of zero while using a min function

Tags: mysql

The intent of my query is to find the minimum sort_order for a particular image_id and item_id for each unique combination of image_id and item_id.  The current query is getting 0 results where the sort_order is equal 0, even though that's a common thing in the table.  The results were all 1 or above.  The query is:

```
    SELECT  
        image_id, 
        item_id, 
        sort_order
    FROM 
        t1
    GROUP BY 
        image_id, 
        item_id
    HAVING 
        MIN(sort_order)
```

Any thoughts?

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Answer (score 1):

You want to use the aggregation function in the select clause:

```
select image_id,
    item_id,
    min(sort_order)
from t1
group by image_id,
    item_id
```

Answer (score 0):

The having clause would return only combintions where the `MIN(sort_order)` is TRUE which is `1`

```
SELECT  
    image_id, 
    item_id, 
    min(sort_order)
FROM 
    t1
GROUP BY 
    image_id, 
    item_id
```